# Fail to Moderation in comment box

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm unable to moderate the comments in the comments box in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Did I miss something in my code?

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '168365613230111',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/" data-num-posts="5" data-width="500"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for ages, try putting this tag in ...

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://yourwebsite.com">
```